# Pip install -e packages don't appear in Docker

Tags: python, docker, pip, docker-compose

I have a `requirements.txt` file containing, amongst others:

```
Flask-RQ==0.2
-e git+https://token:x-oauth-basic@github.com/user/repo.git#egg=repo
```

When I try to build a Docker container using Docker Compose, it downloads both packages, and install them both, but when I do a `pip freeze` there is no sign of the `-e` package. When I try to run the app, it looks as if this package hasn't been installed. Here's the relevant output from the build:

```
Collecting Flask-RQ==0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading Flask-RQ-0.2.tar.gz
Obtaining repo from git+https://token:x-oauth-basic@github.com/user/repo.git#egg=repo (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Cloning https://token:x-oauth-basic@github.com/user/repo.git to ./src/repo
```

And here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app
```

I find this situation very strange and would appreciate any help.

Comment: You appear to have misspelled your directory path in the final line: `COPY . /use/src/app`. Though I'm not really sure what you intended with that, since your `pip install` happens inside the container.

Comment: @Gigablah, my bad, it was a typo. But still, the problem remains the same.

Comment: what does `pip list` output?

Comment: The same as `pip freeze`: the editable package is not there.

Comment: `pip` didn't install the package. Try to install it by hands with verbose output (`-vvv`). Maybe it will give you a hint about cause of the problem

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the editable flag, but have no clue how does this work within Docker...

Comment: @AndreiHorak I think Docker has nothing to do with this. As I said you really need to run pip with verbose output (`pip -vvv install -r requirements.txt`). Also what version of pip do you use?

Comment: I was referring to Docker because editable installs extract the sources in some other directory which *could* be removed by Docker after finishing its step. I will do the verbose thing, but after more thinking, editable installs don't help me that much inside Docker, since it's pretty hard to link them to host files in order to sync changes...so probably I'll drop the flag.

Comment: I have also the problem with `RUN pip install <pkg>` seemingly succeeding but not seeing the packages in the resulting container/image - see my SO question "Docker: RUN pip install boto succeeds but is missing from the resulting image" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964787/docker-run-pip-install-boto-succeeds-but-is-missing-from-the-resulting-image

Answer (score 36):

I ran into a similar issue, and one possible way that the problem can appear is from:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

being set before `pip install`. pip will create the `src/` directory (where the package is installed) inside of the WORKDIR. Now all of this shouldn't be an issue since your app files, when copied over, should not overwrite the `src/` directory.

However, you might be *mounting a volume* to `/usr/src/app`. When you do that, you'll overwrite the `/usr/src/app/src` directory and then your package will not be found.

So one fix is to move WORKDIR after the `pip install`. So your `Dockerfile` will look like:

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

This fixed it for me. Hopefully it'll work for you.

Comment: Actually, this is a very good explanation. Thank you! Still, on my local machine I have the editable installs in some other directory so syncing them to the container may be too much of a hassle...

Answer (score 25):

@mikexstudios is correct, this happens because pip stores the package source in `/usr/src/app/src`, but you're mounting a local directory over top of it, meaning python can't find the package source.

Rather than changing the position of `WORKDIR`, I solved it by changing the pip command to:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --src /usr/local/src
```

Either approach should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are recieving a similar error when installing a git repo from a requirements file under a dockerized container, you may have forgotten to install git.

Here is the error I recieved:

```
Downloading/unpacking CMRESHandler from 
git+git://github.com/zigius/python-elasticsearch-logger.git (from -r 
/home/ubuntu/requirements.txt (line 5))
Cloning git://github.com/zigius/python-elasticsearch-logger.git to 
/tmp/pip_build_root/CMRESHandler
Cleaning up...
Cannot find command 'git'
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
The command '/bin/sh -c useradd ubuntu -b /home && echo 
"ubuntu     ALL     = NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers             && 
chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu && pip install -r /home/ubuntu/requirements.txt returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Here is an example Dockerfile that installs git and then installs all requirements:

```
FROM python:3.5-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git \

ADD . /code       

WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools && pip install -r /home/ubuntu/requirements.txt
```

Now you can use git packages in your requirements file in a Dockerized environment